# Animations doesn't work on a free asset in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I downloaded a few assets for free to use them in my student project, but for some reason, the animations doesn't play.

It does say that the reason for that is because it is static, but nothing happens when I change it to non-static. If I am in the scene, the animations play correctly but guessing that this doesn't matter in this case.

I couldn't really find information as I am not really certain what's causing this.

Please look at the video for more information https://gifyu.com/image/SdxG0

The solution: Had to change it to static while not in play mode (amazing...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change a static GameObject in real-time (Playmode) to non-static. And once it's static, you cannot change it's position or animate because when you mark GameObjects as static, it will do some light calculations beforehand, which will be invalid if the object moves.

Steps to fix is simply to make the GameObject not static BEFORE entering playmode. You can read more about it in the Unity docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StaticObjects.html